# How to access webview content in chrome app

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app

I'm writing a chrome app which loads an external site via .
Executing JavaScript within the loaded page does well with:

```
webview.executeScript();
```

But now I need to read the HTML-Content from that loaded external site in my main chrome app.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Inject a content script, establish messaging between the two?

Comment: Hi Xan, can you please provide a code example or tutorial?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use executeScript for that too:

```
webview.executeScript(
    {code: 'document.documentElement.innerHTML'},
    function(results) {
      // results[0] would have the webview's innerHTML.
    });
```